# Using @font-face slows load time. Can I force the client to cache the font?

Tags: css, font-face

**Update:**
Looks like the header request information is the culprit. How would I change the max-age property of the request header? TIA.

---

Hi, I'm using @font-face on a website and i'm experiencing delayed loading of the text (presumably due to the loading of the font every page). I understand the client has to download the font once to display properly, but every page?

Is there a way I can force the browser to cache that file? Or is there another alternative to speed up the font's loading time? (Is this a question more appropriate to post on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/)?)

Thanks in advance. Worst case, I'll live with the delay, so I don't need any "take off @font-face" answers... ;)

**Additional Information:**

- I've tested this in both Safari (4) and Firefox (3.5RC1) on both Mac and Windows (XP and 7)
- All the browsers I've tested on are currently set up to allow caching (it's on by default)
- The URL is ***not*** dynamic, it's simply "/fonts/font.otf"
- The font URL is correct, as the page loads the font and displays it correctly, albeit slower then normal
- Request Header :

  Cache-Control:max-age=0
  If-Modified-Since:Wed, 24 Jun 2009 03:46:28 GMT
  If-None-Match:W/"484d9f2-a5ac-46d10ff2ebcc0"
  Referer:http://testurl.com/
  User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6; en-us) AppleWebKit/530.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Safari/530.15
- Response headers:

  Connection:Keep-Alive
  Date:Thu, 25 Jun 2009 02:21:31 GMT
  Etag:"484d9f2-a5ac-46d10ff2ebcc0"
  Keep-Alive:timeout=10, max=29
  Server:Apache/2.2.11 (Unix) mod_ssl/2.2.11 OpenSSL/0.9.8i DAV/2 mod_auth_passthrough/2.1 mod_bwlimited/1.4 FrontPage/5.0.2.2635

Comment: Can you post the current headers sent for a request for the font?

Comment: Thanks for asking Matt, I've added it. Looks like the max-age is what's doing it. How would I change that to a longer duration?

Comment: what about the RESPONSE headers? these are just as relevant, if not more.

Comment: Setting max-age is a server and language specific thing. if your on apache have a look at mod_expires

Comment: K, I added the response headers. I'll take a look at mod_expires. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 4):

You can never force a browser to cache something, only encourage it. I can think of no reason why a font file with the correct expires headers wouldn't be cached which brings us to:

- It's a browser bug (you don't say which browser)
- Your cache control headers are missing or wrong
- Your browser is configured to not cache anything (do images cache?)
- Your font URL is dynamic so the browser thinks each request is for a different resource
- The font face file is actually missing or or the URL misspelt.
- The delay is NOT caused by the font download (you did say you *presume* this is the issue)

I think more information is in order.

EDIT: To set cache control is a server and language specific thing. Look at [mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_expires.html) for information on caching in Apache.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I've updated the post to reflect some of your points. I'll also look more in detail at the cache control header information to make sure I didn't make a mistake there.

The reason I presume it's a download issue is when I test the site on my local server (where download speeds are obviously next to nil) the special font loads in normal time (the same as regular text).

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure your font files are cachable? Just like other static content, they should have far-future expires dates, and their headers should be configured to allow them to be cached. If you are hosting your fonts on a server farm, you will want to make sure your etag header is normalized across all the servers in the farm...otherwise subsequent requests for the font may force it to be re-downloaded from an alternative server even though the same data was already downloaded from another server.

Comment: Great comment, however, that's not what's happening as I'm not hosting the file on a server farm. As for the file's headers, yes, they are configured to allow caching, I'm trying to "force" caching though (as the file will never change).

Comment: In addition to allowing caching, make sure you have a far-future expiration date. Quite often I'll enable caching on some piece of static content, but won't give it a far-future expires date...and it will refuse to cache (FireFox is the best test of this, as it is excessively picky about having exactly the right headers in order to cache something...Opera is FAR more lenient, and IE is unpredictable.)

Comment: I'll look into it and make sure I've got them set right. Thanks for the heads-up!