# Reloading my font on website

Tags: asp.net, html, caching, client-side, custom-font

we used on website some nonbasic font, but problem is with reloading - u can see basic font and then reload to our font on every page. Its possible cache it or somehow save it to client? Reloading on every page is terrible.

web: http://ktwebstudio.cz/

We are using windows hosting and ASP.NET.

I FOUND IT:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

And everything is OK.

Comment: Looks like you're having the same problem as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1036309/using-font-face-slows-load-time-can-i-force-the-client-to-cache-the-font

Answer (score 0):

If using custom fonts on your web page is what you mean, then CSS is the best way to do it. It works quite well and I can tell you that from personal experience. Here's how you do it:

**NOTE:**

- You can define as many custom fonts as you like using the example below.
- Internet Explorer uses EOT fonts instead of TTF.
- Use the font-family you specified to use the font in your web page.

  ```
  @font-face
  {
      font-family: name_of_font;
      src: 
          url('url of name_of_font.ttf' */), 
          url('url of name_of_font.eot' */);
  }
  ```

Example:

`<p style="font-family: name_of_font; font-size: 100%;">
Your text here with the custom font you specified...
</p>`

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible to stop the reloading of basic fonts to embedded CSS3 fonts, even if the fonts are cached! This is a web browser problem. Some web browsers do this (Opera), and some don't (IE9).